# Lightning datatable throws an error when attempting to use onsort event

Tags: javascript, datatable, salesforce, lwc

When attempting to sort a lightning datatable, the error 'NoErrorObjectAvailable' pops up.

HTML:

````
       key-field="Id"
       data={jobItems}
       columns={columns}
       hide-checkbox-column
       onrowaction={handleRowAction}
       onsort={updateColumnSorting}
   ></lightning-datatable>```

JS:
updateColumnSorting(event)
{          
   var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
   var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;

   console.log('## fieldName: ' + fieldName);
   console.log('## sortDirection: ' + sortDirection);
            
}```

ERROR:
````

[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs70/auraFW/javascript/7p9HLMpgnV2GO9Mq/aura_prod.js:948:169
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs70/auraFW/javascript/7p9HLMpgnV2GO9Mq/aura_prod.js:948:362
ln.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs70/auraFW/javascript/7p9HLMpgnV2GO9Mq/aura_prod.js:12:12146
ln.fireSortedColumnChange()@https://COMPANY_NAME--SANDBOX_NAME.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:2:66247
ln.handleUpdateColumnSort()@https://COMPANY_NAME--SANDBOX_NAME.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:2:65875```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The mistake was putting on sort function inside another function by mistake in VS Code. It was saving just fine with proper highlighting and all. It only errored out when I tried to write a getter function right after it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue today when trying to dispatch a custom event from a `lightning-combobox`'s `onchange` handler. What helped me to get rid of the error was to change `var` into `const`.

**Doesn't work**

```
 handleSearchOptionChange(event) {
      console.log(event.detail, event.detail.value);
      this.selectedBoatTypeId = event.detail.value;

      var searchEvent = new CustomEvent('search', { detail:{ boatTypeId: event.detail.value }});
      this.dispatchEvent(searchEvent);
 }
```

**Working**

```
 handleSearchOptionChange(event) {
      console.log(event.detail, event.detail.value);
      this.selectedBoatTypeId = event.detail.value;

      const searchEvent = new CustomEvent('search', { detail:{ boatTypeId: event.detail.value }});
      this.dispatchEvent(searchEvent);
 }
```

Not sure if it's the same in your particular case, but wanted to share it since it costed me about 45 minutes of debugging...

Comment: Thank you, Sven, but it was not it. But your comment is useful nonetheless.